# Linux, change order columns without awk

Tags: bash

I need help to change order of the columns. 
I have input:

```
1 ls  
2 bash  
3 cd
```

I need to change numbers and word.

Output must be

```
cd 3  
bash 2  
ls 1
```

I can't use the command awk.

Comment: Why can't you use `awk`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
tac input | while read a b; do echo "$b" "$a"; done
```